# Diff in Diff with covariates vs Diff in Diff with Propensity Score Matching

Tags: difference-in-difference

To measure the impact of a specific event, we can use Diff in Diff. Since in my case, I can't randomize, I need to think of a way to control for other covariates. I know how to implement the two different methods in this scenario. But can anyone explain the pros and cons of the two methods? Assuming I am using the same covariates. Thanks.